# How can I add the facebook like button inside my single.php in wordpress without any plugin

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

If this question is not appropriate for the site I am sorry. In my wordpress site I want to add facebook like button with dynamic permalink in the single.php file but without any plugin. In other words i want to add like button after the post when the single post is open via single.php file. Any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `single.php` file inside the loop

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
....
<?php the_content(); ?>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=85&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:85px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[You can read this.](http://mashable.com/2010/05/07/wordpress-facebook-like-buttons/)

Answer (score 1):

[This may work](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-wordpress/)

Comment: This may help the `OP` but you should answer with some code example otherwise you should use comment, anyway +1 for the link, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this below code into functions.php.

```
      function setFacebookLike($content) {
  global $post;
      if($post->post_type=="post") {

          $content.= '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='.get_permalink($post->ID).'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=85&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:85px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
      }
      return $content;
  }
  add_filter ('the_content', 'setFacebookLike');
```